# Does Bing News Search API's C# SDK support querying a private endpoint using an App Id?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-news-search-api

The [quick-start sample documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/quickstarts/client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-csharp) shows how one can query the public endpoint using a subscription key.

But say I have a private Bing News API endpoint and an AppId generated that identifies me - Can I use the C# SDK to call this endpoint using my AppId? Or would I be forced to call it as a REST API by creating a HttpWebRequest?

Is there something that allows the private API provider to generate subscription keys for their consumers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, only the `subscription key` can be used to define the client in the SDK. Such as `var client = new NewsSearchClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key));`.

Currently, private sites such as `https://pa***2.cognitiveservices.azure.com` and `key` are not supported to define clients. It is recommended to raise a support ticket on portal to confirm this.

If you need to use C# code to implement the bing search function, it is recommended to use `HttpClient` and C# code to send http requests.

You can use [HttpHelper](https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleProj/blob/master/ODatafilter/HttpHelper.cs) in my sample code.